# KeychainTouchID iOS 8 and 9

Tags: ios, ios8, keychain, touch-id

I followed apple's sample code in integrating touch id and keychain.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html

While everything work great in iOS 9, in iOS8 there is an issue where if I try to access the saved encrypted info, the OS doesn't present the scanning pop-up and ask the user to scan there fingers, its just give me the data right away. What kind of modifications I need to apply to apple's sample to have it work correctly in iOS8 and present the scanning popup when needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check this dictionary creation for addItemAsync

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
        (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"SampleService",
        (__bridge id)kSecValueData: [@"SECRET_PASSWORD_TEXT" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
        (__bridge id)kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI: @YES,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject
```

kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI is deprecated value in iOS 9.

```
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI
        __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED_MSG(__MAC_10_10, __MAC_10_11, __IPHONE_8_0, __IPHONE_9_0, "Use a kSecAuthenticationUI instead.");
extern const CFStringRef kSecUseAuthenticationUI
        __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_11, __IPHONE_9_0);
```

This should help.